# Transmission on FreeNAS does not call script on completion

Tags: bash, freebsd, transmission-daemon

I have been trying to get this running for over a week and am at a loss.  I am trying to call a script on completion by using the settings.json config like so:

```
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/posttorrent.sh",
```

My script is in the root of the jail and is owned by transmission.  I have also checked permissions on the file (which are 755) and have run chmod +x /posttorrent.sh.

I have even simplified the file to just output to a log file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$TR_TORRENT_NAME is completed" >> /posttorrent.log
```

However, thus far, I still do not have a posttorrent.log file anywhere, no matter what file I download.  I am not totally sure if I am on the right track as Transmission is set to log level 3 and yet I do not even see the calls to the script in /var/log/debug.log.  I am sure I am missing something easy as others have been able to get this working, I am just out of options now as I think I have read and/or tried everything I could find in relation to this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: `"/posttorrent.sh"` is very suspect, don't you mean `"/path/to/posttorrent.sh"` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it is possible its wrong, however the script is in the root of the jail which would seem to be /posttorrent.sh as the /path/to/posttorrent.sh.  Certainly works that way from ssh though I have no idea if that is true from the daemon.  I would think it is but clearly I don't know much :-/

Comment: OK, I'm not a FreeNAS user, but I thought I should ask the question. Good luck!

Comment: Does `/path/to/jail/bin/bash` exist?

Comment: @kdhp that does not exist, however bash is available as a command and I do have it in /path/to/jail/usr/local/bin and usr/ports/shells/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is relying on `/bin/bash` being present inside of the jail.
You can either change the script to use `/bin/sh`, change `/bin/bash`
to `/usr/bin/env bash`, or link `/path/to/port/bin/bash` to
`/usr/local/bin/bash` (or wherever `bash` is located relative to the
jail directory, but if it exists it should be in `/usr/local/bin`).

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /path/to/jail/bin/bash
```

Also, the root directory (by default) is only writable by `root`, so
the `transmission` user would not have [permission](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/permissions.html) to create
the log file in the root directory.  To properly allow creation of
the log file change the destination directory to one that the
`transmission` user has [permission](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/permissions.html) to write to.  For example
`/var/db/transmission/posttorrent.log`, if using the FreeNAS plugin.
A directory can be created for the `transmission` user using the
[install utility](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-stable&arch=amd64&format=html):

```
install -d -o transmission -g transmission /home/transmission
```

Alternatively the log file can be created manually using the
[install utility](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-stable&arch=amd64&format=html), or the owner can be set with chown:

```
install -o transmission -g transmission -m 644 /dev/null /posttorrent.log
# or on an existing log file
chown transmission /posttorrent.log
chgrp transmission /posttorrent.log
# normally the mode bits will already be 644
chmod 644 /posttorrent.log
```

Transmission will also [rewrite the configuration file when it
exits](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles).  So `transmission-daemon` has to be stopped before
editing the settings file.  However, if using the Transmission plugin,
the settings are stored in a SQLite database

(`/usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/transmissionUI/transmission.db`)

and the settings file will be recreated from the database on
startup.  [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) can be used to manually edit the database, or the plugin's settings can be edited on the FreeNAS web UI.

```
sqlite3 /usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/transmissionUI/transmission.db <<EOF
UPDATE freenas_transmission SET enable=1;
UPDATE freenas_transmission SET script_post_torrent="/posttorrent.sh";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure this fits.  I did try it to be safe (amending the top line of my script to point at bash) but it didn't change anything.  As I mentioned, bash is installed as a command in the Jail.  In fact, it is not installed anywhere else.  I get your point about it pointing to the right place which is why I changed it, but it can also be called through the ssh session, where I am in the Jail the entire time.

Comment: @Duffmaster33  Multiple things could be overwriting the settings file.  Hopefully some of the information added to the answer helps.

Comment: The settings file is not the issue, I have verified multiple times that it is correct.  I have also been editing it through the GUI, which does not have the issue of overwriting.

Comment: @Duffmaster33 Does the transmission user have permission to create the log file?

Comment: Great question, I honestly don't know.  I did add transmission to the wheel group cause I was afraid of permissions issues, but am very foggy on if that means they have permissions or not.  How would I check?

Comment: @Duffmaster33 `ls -dl /` or `stat /`, unless you changed the permissions they should be `rwxr-xr-x` (only writable by root).

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I get:
root@transmission_1:/ # ls -dl /
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel  28 Jan 17 09:56 /  Does that mean only root has access?  How can I fix?

Comment: @Duffmaster33 You can change the destination directory to somewhere that the `transmission` user has [permission](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/permissions.html) to write to.  For example,`/var/db/transmission/posttorrent.log`, if using the FreeNAS plugin.  Alternatively, you could manually set the [permissions](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/permissions.html) of the log file, for example changing the owner.  `chown transmission /posttorrent.log`

Comment: Ah!  That did it, apparently Transmission likes to fail silently when the script fails.  Thank you so much!  If you update your answer, I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: @Duffmaster33 The answer as been updated with the permission issues addressed.